# Windows 7 SSH file server

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssh, file-sharing

I have looked at the other posts, but have not quite found an answer

I have a question about windows file sharing over SSH. I have copssh installed and it is working for Remote desktop connections. I have port 22 forwarded on my router etc. I connect from a Mac or Putty with this address:

ssh -l copsshusername 3391:localhost:3389 [external ip]

That works fine.

I would like to configure Windows 7 to allow my ssh account that I use to login, access to certain shared folders. I have documents and videos and things that I would like to be able to download externally.

I have done this before on Linux and a long time ago on XP, but I cannot figure out what I am missing on Windows 7.

There is a designated SSH user that copssh uses to run the service and that I use to to login as.

I have googled and googled and have not found a solution that does everything I need that is why I am turning here for ideas.

I hope I am explaining this correctly. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: so you just want sftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your configuration correctly, you don't need to give the ssh user any special privileges. On the client computer (from which you connect using ssh) you just connect to localhost. Of course, that computer can't run fileserver on the same port itself.

You may need to use the same port number (that is, 3389) on both ends of the tunnel, so that the client computer recognizes it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I have it narrowed down to a configuration error on the client side. I'll post something if I figure it out.